# Using existing foreign key value in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Entity Framework Code First. I have two model classes, Currency and Invoice:

```
public class Currency
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
    public double Rate { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public double RateOfExchange { get; set; }
    public double CurrencyAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I have some initialized my database with some Currency values. Whenever I add a new Invoice, I want it to use existing values from the Currency table for its Currency property but every time I create a new Invoice value and assign its Currency property with an existing value from the Currency table, it creates a duplicate value in the currency table. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Are you setting the `Currency` property or the `CurrencyID` property (it needs to be the latter)

Answer (score 1):

Above the line:

```
public virtual Currency Currency { get; set;}
```

Add the following attribute:

```
[ForeignKey("CurrencyID")]
```